# Determine type of function from points

Tags: functions, regression

Assume $A$ is a set of points in $\mathbb{R^2}$. The points of $A$ were generated from a function that is either linear, polynomial, or exponential, but you don't know which. Is it possible to determine the function type from $A$ (though you don't need to determine the exact function itself)? If this is possible, must $|A| ≥ k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{R}$ in order to make this determination?

Comment: Linear and exponential functions are determined by just two "parameters", so knowing two points should (usually) suffice to determine those parameters, and a third point would check of they are valid. Polynomials, however, can have an arbitrarily large degree, and thus an arbitrarily large number of coefficients, so you can never be sure you've nailed it down - unless you know those are those only three possibilities and you've ruled out the other two. But you'll still never be sure about the degree - additional points could always require more terms.